# ASP.NET Core MVC POST method a model with foreign key Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to do a `POST` where the model has a foreign key field, but I want to set this value to the creator's id. I have one model called "Store" with a `ApplicationUserId` FK . I tried to pass a new object "Store" containing the `ApplicationUserId` to the view on the GET but when I submit, the `ApplicationUserId` field is null. I also tried to set the field manually on the controller, but the model state is already invalid at this point

My action:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Store store)
        {
            store.ApplicationUser = currentUser
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                _context.Add(store);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(store);
        }
```

My model:

```cs
    public class Store
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is your action Create(Store store) for? Are you trying to show a view on the screen or  save  store in DB. Please  show us some more code before you will be downvoted with somebody.

Comment: If the value arrives null, that's almost always a serialization issue. 
How is your model Store, can you edit your post with that? and how you get "current user"?

Comment: @Sergey, this is to save in the DB, I edited the post.

Comment: @RodRamírez, I get the current user using the "UserManager" class. Only the ApplicationUserId is null. I edited the post with my model.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see UserId property in your Store class

Comment: You model doesn't match your action `store.UserId`... the model doesn't have a UserId

Comment: And now, after your edit, your model doesn't have a ApplicationUserId property...

Comment: Perhaps try showing us your actual code, that compiles, that doesn't work

Comment: Just finalized editing. Now this is the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign UserId (or any another property) and it will work and will be saved to DB, but it WILL NOT affect your ModelState. ModelState will be the same as it was posted from client side. There are 2 ways to fix it:

1. Assign UserId in the model in your get action of controler before you use your model to return View and keep in you view as a hidden field.
2. Check what property of ModelState is not valid and if it only UserId, assign it and save. I can show you the code that can define what is invalid in Modeld

Comment: Thanks, Sergey! I though that after assigning the User Id my model would turn valid. And another problem was that I was not adding the property as a hidden field. Now I added the field and I check on my action if the user didn't change it in the front end.